# how to check download resumed or not in ASIHTTPRequest..?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, asihttprequest

hi i am downloading file from server using ASIHTTPRequest in my iphone application

but i am not getting any callbacks to know whether downloading resumed after i stopped and  resume it again .

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:pv];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:path];
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:tempPath];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
[[self queue] addOperation:request]; //queue is an NSOperationQueue
```

any body now how to check the download resumed or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set up a delegate for the request?
If you post the code it would help.

Comment: what does your requestDone: implementation and declaration look like?